# JPanel and JFrame same size, or not?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size, jpanel

I'm trying to get `JFrame` and `JPanel` the same size, so I can align everything perfectly. But when I try this, the `JPanel` and `JFrame` appear to not be the same size.

Here's my code:

```
public static void createWindow(){

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setSize(500,300);
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to " + name,SwingConstants.CENTER);
    welcomeLabel.setSize(300,30);
    welcomeLabel.setLocation((contentPane.getWidth()/2)-(welcomeLabel.getWidth()/2),5); //Put the welcomeLabel in the uppercenter; does noet work.
    contentPane.add(welcomeLabel);

    JLabel versionLabel = new JLabel("TBRPG-Engine " + Main.getVersionNumber(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
    versionLabel.setSize(300,30);       
    versionLabel.setLocation(contentPane.getWidth()-versionLabel.getWidth(),contentPane.getHeight());   
    contentPane.add(versionLabel);      

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(contentPane);
    frame.setTitle(name);
    frame.setSize(contentPane.getWidth(),contentPane.getHeight());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

The `contentPane` is bigger than the `frame` when I run this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to make `contentPane` panel to actually be one. `frame.setContentPane(contentPane);` See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container) Then you would not need to worry about its size.

Comment: @PM77-1 Ehm, okay. But when I try this, the exact same thing happens...

Comment: Then `pack()` your frame before making it visible. It will disregard all your dimensions and make frame the right size to hold all its components.

Comment: Yes, you should use Layout Managers, on a side note calling contentPane to that JPanel is confusing, that JPanel is inside the contentPane of the frame. ContentPane is an object Container of the JFrame class and it contains everything that you add to the frame (except menubar). Doing frame.add(JComponent) is a convenience method for frame.getContentPane().add(JComponent). At the same time that is equivalent to frame.getContentPane().add(JComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER) because contentPane by default uses BorderLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of absolute position use LayoutManagers.   Choose the correct one for your desired arrangement and it will not only simplify your code it will make it easier to update in the future.

In this case it looks like a BorderLayout could be used to arrange your GUI.  Always you remember you can layer different managers together to create more complicated effects.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look!